# How to add html <br> tags into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mailto

I have a button that when clicked opens email and fills the body with variables. This looks too messy though as it all appears on one line. Could I just chuck in a br tag inbetween each variable so they appear on a new line?

Thanks. Here is code:

```
$("#buttonLink").click (function() {
            window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=My frame Type: ' + frameType + ' My Frame Background: ' + frameBackground + ' My text: ' + yourText + ' My Text design: ' + textDesign); 
        });
```

I'm thinking something like:

```
$("#buttonLink").click (function() {
        window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=My frame Type: ' + frameType + <br> + ' My Frame Background: ' + frameBackground + <br> + ' My text: ' + yourText + <br> +' My Text design: ' + textDesign); 
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ASCII code which is `%0D%0A`, like this:

```
window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=My frame Type: ' + frameType +'%0D%0A My Frame Background: ' + frameBackground + '%0D%0A My text: ' + yourText + '%0D%0A My Text design: ' + textDesign);
```

Strictly speaking should the white spaces also be replaced. Use the ASCII code which is `%20`, like this:

```
window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My%20Frame&body=My%20frame%20Type:%20' + frameType +'%0D%0A%20My%20Frame%20Background:%20' + frameBackground + '%0D%0A%20My%20text:%20' + yourText + '%0D%0A%20My%20Text%20design:%20' + textDesign);
```

Answer (score 2):

try some thing like this

```
            $("#buttonLink").click (function() {
    //try this 

        var brtag= document.createElement("br");

    //then 
    brtag.id = "your_id"
     brtag.setAttribute("class", "your_class");

    //and so on

//then do rest of your stuffs
                });
```

it might work ...(do let me know it it works !)

Comment: It may but it seems awfully complex. I found a simpler solution but thanks anyway.